# aligned-environment in tabularx - fail to align vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, tabularx

I try to have a simple tabularx-table in which the cell content is vertically aligned to the top. While this works as expected for text, two aligned-environments in adjacent cells are vertically centered for no reason I could find.

How do I get the content of the first tabularx-environment aligned to the top?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l}
        \hline
        $
            \begin{aligned}
                a &= 1 \\
                b &= 2
            \end{aligned}
        $
        &
        $
            \begin{aligned}
                c =& 3
            \end{aligned}
        $\\  
        \hline          
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l}
        \hline
            \lipsum[1]
        &
            $
                \begin{aligned}
                    c =& 3
                \end{aligned}
            $\\  
        \hline          
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: vertical alignment in tabularx fails for "aligned" environment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
\begin{aligned}[t]
```

to align on the top.

Comment: Although I don't understand why the aligned-environment in the second table behaves differently.